# How to Cast string in View

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple view that takes a varchar and converts it to a float.

```
Select CAST(TRIM(Measurement) AS float) as Measurement
from MyTable
where Type = 'Some Value'
```

Now the view sees the column as a float, however when i try to query my view with a where clasue of  Measurement = 10, then I get the error:

```
Error converting data type varchar to float.
```

I know the string value will always be a number (I have checked many times).  I also got this through multiple rounds of testing before this error popped up in prod.  My guess is that there are other measurements in the table that are not part of my results, but are causing this error (those measurements may not have existing during the testing).

Is there a way to clean up the query so the results are always treated as a float?

Thanks

Comment: Locate the rows containing incorrect measurements and fix the data. The CHANGE THE DATATYPE of the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clearly have bad values in the column.  You can find them using a regular expression (in most databases) or a `try_` function in SQL Server.

For instance:

```
Select Measurement
from MyTable
where Type = 'Some Value' AND try_convert(float, measurement) is null;
```

Or:

```
where type = 'Some Value' and
      not measurement ~ '^-?[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+$'
```

Th `~` is Postgres for a regular expression match.  Other databases have similar functionality with different syntax.

Comment: Add `try_convert() is null and measurement is not null` to be mor precise.

Comment: Right after i posted this, i noticed the problem, I was trimming the wrong field!!!!  I feel like such a fool.  added this to my view:  CASE ISNUMERIC(TRIM(MeasurementValue)) WHEN 1 THEN CAST(TRIM(MeasurementValue)) AS float) ELSE null END as newValue